# SparseCategoricalcrossEntropy(from_logits=True) internally apply softmax?

Tags: loss-function

Regarding Tensorflow/Keras [SparseCategoricalcrossEntropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy).

`SparseCategoricalcrossEntropy(from_logits=True)` expects the logits that has not been normalized by softmax. Then does SparseCategoricalcrossEntropy applies softmax internally?

I suppose applying softmax would not be required internally as taking `argmax` would give the index expected.

Please help clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Softmax function is called when `logit=True`

Infact, if we check the keras code [[*Link*]](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/f630ad87a01ed2b4d08f91e5553b50c6a85601f6/keras/backend.py#L4878), the softmax output is ignored in every condition and `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` is called. This function calculate softmax prior to cross_entropy as explained [[*Here*]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34243720/2187625)

> *I suppose applying softmax would not be required internally as taking argmax would give the index expected.*

Predicting the class is not the only task here. It has to calculate the appropriate loss value to provide feedback to the network

If the target is in probability values[OHE] *i.e. sum=1*, not an open-ended logit *i.e. [-inf, inf]*. So the output should be similarly normalized prior to the loss calculation.